# Why am I having FPS issues?

Tags: diablo-iii

I am playing Diablo 3: ROS and having FPS issues while my girlfriend's laptop runs the game like a dream.

My setup:

- Intel i7, 4770k 3.5gHz,
- 16GB RAM,
- 2 Nvidia GeForce GTX760s (SLI),
- 750 Watt power supply,
- and the game is installed on my SSD.

I had no problems a week ago, and now I get between 7-25 FPS. The lag is unplayable, and before anyone mentions it could be network lag I'm hardwired, my girlfriend's laptop is wireless and not even the slightest hint of lag on her computer.

Also I'd like to make note that the FPS results are the same at both maxed out graphic and minimum graphic options in game.

Any advice helps!

Comment: Did you update your drivers recently? Maybe that's what causes the lags?

Comment: all drivers are up to date

Comment: Untick the "reflection" box in the video setting and try again and try with Vertical sync enabled and disabled to see. Btw I have the same spec as you and the game is running smoothly. If that does not do the trick try to disable the SLI, I had some driver issue with diablo and the SLI enabled with the latest version of the drivers.

Comment: enabling vsync helped a little... reflections were never on, when I disabled the sli I saw more lag spikes

Comment: is your ssd (almost) full? that might cause some lower fps.. you could try to reinstall the game to see if that works

Comment: figured it out, thanks for all of the help, I removed the second g-card and there's virtually no lag! the 750W power supply isnt enough for both cards. Going to upgrade it this weekend and then she'll run like a dream again

Comment: @user72860 you should post that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, fps decreased and it was difficult to even move the cursor. Cursory googling lead to [this forum post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12471016978?page=1).

The advice given was to set Window's display font setting to the default value of 100%. I was at 125% and changing it back to 100% helped my situation. The fps returned to normal.